# Which query is more appropriate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
   TABLE T1                    TABLE T2
   +----+------------+         +----+------------+
   | Id |   Name     |         | Id |  Some_Data |
   +----+------------+         +----+------------+
   |    |            |         |    |            |
```

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id WHERE T1.Id=1001
```

Query2:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id WHERE T2.Id=1001
```

If T2 has 10 million rows of which only 100 has Id=1001, which of the above query is the more appropriate one to use?  Or it doesn't matter as SQL Server is smart enough to know what to do best?

Thanks.

Comment: That might depend on the indexes on the tables. Also, have you had a look at the execution plan for the 2 queries? What do they show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Index is available on both the ID columns some variant of hash join will be used and the order of the table is irrelevant

If Index is not available then it makes sense to have the where clause on the left hand side table just to make the NL join more efficient .(I have a feeling that based on statistics of participating table MSSQLSERVER will be intelligent to swap the order by itself)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON (T1.Id=T2.Id AND T2.Id=1001)
```

they say putting `T2.Id=1001` will filter and then select rows but putting it in `Where T2.Id=1001` will first select all rows for condition `T1.Id=T2.Id` and then apply `T2.Id=1001`

Comment: as @astander commented much of the performance will depend on indexes

Comment: It's almost certainly *not* true that all rows will be joined before the `WHERE` clause is considered. The optimizer will be able to push the `WHERE` clause predicate down to the table/index seek/scan, only rows matching that predicate will ever enter the join operator.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well it looks so obvious that optimizer will not allow this silly thing. But I was taking it on face value till now, but think this is a good practice and will stick to it when ever I can myself set the criteria as early as possible in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

As per me Query2 is more appropriate.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id WHERE T2.Id=1001
```

It will restrict the rows returned so it will be more efficient, still you can check [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173294.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to have non-clustered indexes on both the id columns and then use any of the above query in order to get results fast. Else I don't think you will be able to process the query faster in any of the above queries.Indexes are must in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the join - with many millions of rows - always come first and only after that will come the where clause.
Try this instead on your tables and see the timestamps in the messages tab:

```
declare @t1 table (id int, name nvarchar(100));
declare @t2 table (id int, name nvarchar(100));

insert into @t1 (id, name) values (1, 'a')
insert into @t1 (id, name) values (2, 'b')
insert into @t1 (id, name) values (3, 'c')
insert into @t1 (id, name) values (4, 'd')
insert into @t1 (id, name) values (5, 'e')

insert into @t2 (id, name) values (5, 'e')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (5, 'f')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (5, 'g')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (5, 'h')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (5, 'i')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (6, 'j')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (7, 'k')
insert into @t2 (id, name) values (8, 'l')

print getdate()
-- this is your select statement
select * from @t1 t1 inner join @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t1.id = 5;
print getdate()
-- this is your select statement
select * from @t1 t1 inner join @t2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.id = 5;
print getdate()
-- this is done with a WITH to do the filtering beforehand
-- of course, indices will affect the performance a lot
with w2 (id, name) as (select * from @t2 where id = 5) 
select * from w2 inner join @t1 t1 on w2.id = t1.id
print getdate()
```

Of course, ignore my sample data and use your tables like in the WITH clause.

Comment: The query engine doesn't actually have to execute the query in the order it's written in

Comment: That's clear, it's what the optimizer is for. But I'm kind of surprised: I swear I read somewhere that a join has higher precedence then a where, so the server makes the join first and then it filters the results. Now I took a look at the execution plan of my code and it is absolutely the same for the last 3 statements, no matter if with or without a WITH. So again, I'm puzzled. And have to find that source of info ...

Answer (score 1):

What about first filtering and then joining

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
JOIN (SELECT Id FROM T2 WHERE T2.Id=1001) T2
ON T1.Id=T2.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a real question I am facing, and the database is from a third-party software product where I have read only access to generate some reports.

From all the very helpful answerers, I gather that there is no straightforward answer.  I conclude from the postings that: first ensure the keyed columns are indexed, and then let SQL Server take care of the optimization.

Thanks to all.